# Is there a postgis geometry viewer in JetBrains DataGrip?

Tags: pycharm, postgis, datagrip

pgadmin4 offers PostGIS geometry viewer

https://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/272-pgAdmin4-now-offers-PostGIS-geometry-viewer.html

Is there similar in JetBrains DataGrip or PyCharm?

Comment: why close this? i do not seek recommendations, this was a straightforward question and i got a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the geo-viewer was introduced in **DataGrip 2020.1**:
https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/whatsnew/2020-1/#data-editor

Instructions to enable:

> 1. In the Database tool window (View | Tool Windows | Database), double-click the table with geographical data.
> 2. Click the Show Options Menu icon (Show Options Menu icon) and select Show Geo Viewer.
> 3. Read the notification about possible risks of enabling JCEF. If you accept the risk, click Enable JCEF.
> 4. In the Restart Required window, click Restart Now.
> 5. After the restart, press Ctrl+F5 or reopen the table with geographical data.
> 6. Click the Show Options Menu icon (Show Options Menu icon) and select Show Geo Viewer.

[image]

Comment: @avesse those are actually instructions to *disable* JCEF in case if the IDE crashes.

Comment: I can confirm that his also works with geometry data in SQL Server. There was no prompt to enable JCEF however and I was unable to locate the configuration file that supposedly dictates if it's enable. The docs seem a bit out of date. I was able to just get it working out of the box on DG 2021.2 but I had to add a computed column with `geography_text as geographycol.STAsText()`